# Split string by character in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to split this code by ',' in C#.

Sample string:

> 'DC0''008_','23802.76','23802.76','23802.76','Comm,erc,','2f17','3f44c0ba-daf1-44f0-a361-'

I can use string.split(',') but as you can see 'Comm,erc,' is split up by

> comm
> erc

also 'DC0''008_' should split up as

> 'DC0''008_'

not as

> 'DC0'
>
> '008_'

The expected output should be like this:

> 'DC0''008_'
>
> '23802.76'
>
> '23802.76'
>
> '23802.76'
>
> 'Comm,erc,'
>
> '2f17'
>
> '3f44c0ba-daf1-44f0-a361-'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` can do it but regex will be more complex.

You can use [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx) using this simpler regex:

```
'[^']*'
```

and get all quoted strings in a collection.

**Code:**

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"'[^']*'");
```

To print all the matched values:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"'[^']*'"))
         Console.WriteLine("Found {0}", match.Value);
```

To store all matched values in an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"'[^']*'")) {
   list.add(match.Value);
}
```

---

**EDIT:** As per comments below if OP wants to consume `''` in the captured string then use this lookaround regex:

```
'.*?(?<!')'(?!')
```

`(?<!')'(?!')` means match a single quote that is not surrounded by another single quote.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dMZYWo/1)

Comment: How can i convert to array string

Comment: @VenkatRJV ```Regex.Matches(input, @"'[^']*'").Select(x => x.Value).ToArray()```

Comment: Thanks @Jules, that is very helpful.

Comment: @Jules That does not work. `MatchCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` and thus doesn't have access to LINQ extension methods.

Comment: @Abion47 yeah, this one's better!

Comment: what if it has double quote in string example 'DC000''8_DC','0002' The expected output should be 'DC000''8_DC' and '0002'

Comment: @RJV: For that use `'.*?(?<!')'(?!')` regex

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Regex to get all the things inside the commas and apostrophes:

```
(?<=')[^,].*?(?=')
```

[Regex101 Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/NPMaQy/1)

To convert it into a string array, you can use the following:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(strInput, "(?<=')[^,].*?(?=')");
var array = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

EDIT: If you want it to be able to capture double quotes, then the Regex that will match it in every case becomes unwieldy. At this point, It's better to just use a simpler pattern with `Regex.Split`:

```
var matches = Regex.Split(strInput, "^'|'$|','")
                   .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: what if it has double quote in string example 'DC000''8_DC','0002' The expected output should be 'DC000''8_DC'           and      '0002'

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication15
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "'DC0008_','23802.76','23802.76','23802.76','Comm,erc,','2f17','3f44c0ba-daf1-44f0-a361-'";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(str, "(?<=')[^,].*?(?=')");
            var array = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
            foreach (var item in array)
            Console.WriteLine("'" + item + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With double quote inside, it wont be a single string.

Comment: your code is excellent except it is not including the single quotes after spliting

Answer (score 0):

it is good to modify your string then split it so that you will achieve what you want like some thing below

```
string data = "'DC0008_','23802.76','23802.76','23802.76','Comm,erc,','2f17','3f44c0ba-daf1-44f0-a361-'";

data = Process(data); //process before split i.e for the time being replace outer comma with some thing else like '@'

string[] result = data.Split('@'); // now it will work lolz not confirmed and tested
```

the Process() function is below

```
private string Process(string input)
{
   bool flag = false;
   string temp="";
   char[] data = input.ToCharArray();
   foreach(char ch in data)
   {
     if(ch == '\'' || ch == '"')
         if(flag)
           flag=false;
         else
           flag=true;

      if(ch == ',')
       {
           if(flag) //if it is inside ignore else replace with @
             temp+=ch;
           else
             temp+="@";
       }
      else
          temp+=ch;
   }
 return temp;
}
```

see output here http://rextester.com/COAH43918